# Adding to Style.Triggers instead of overriding them in a derived style

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, wpf-style

Is it possible to, instead of overriding all the triggers of the default style when setting the Style.Triggers property in a derived style, add the the base style's list of triggers?

I.E. if I had:

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Background" Value="Red">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

could I do:

```
<Style x:Key="DerivedErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Background" Value="Red">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

without losing the functionality of the BorderBrush changing to red with the background? Kind of a contrived example but I wanted to keep it simple. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried this yourself first? I've tried it and there is not any overriding here, ***unless*** the `Setter` in the derived style sets the same property which is set in the based style (the `BorderBrush` in this case).

Comment: that can be achieved programmaticly, perhaps as an attached behavior.

Comment: @KingKing wow you're totally right haha. I could've sworn it didn't work before but it seems to work fine. Thanks.